# Is there a name for the kind of perimeter you get if you tighten a rope around an object?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

Is there a name for the perimeter that you get if you tighten a rope around an object, here a 2d object.

[image]

Is "circumventing perimeter" a good name for the red line?

I asked that in the mathchat already, but maybe there is another name for it.

Comment: [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?